# auto play using flowplayer in ios devices

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

Is there any way to auto play videos using flow player in iOS devices? I have searched a lot and couldn't find out anything.

I have used the below code to display videos:`

```
        <source src="file2.mp4" type="video/mp4">


        <object id="flash_fallback_1"  class="vjs-flash-fallback"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf">

            <param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.2.7.swf">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="config={'clip':[{'url': 'file2.mp4','autoPlay':true,'autoBuffering':true}]}">
        </object>
    </video>`
```

Comment: [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html): "In Safari on iOS... preload and autoplay are disabled. ...JavaScript `play()` and `load()` methods are also inactive until the user initiates playback, unless the `play()` or `load()` method is triggered by user action." Thus, `<video>` won't autoplay, and Flash is not supported on iOS, so there's no way to achieve this on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly impossible on iOS, user interaction is required to play video. On a related note, audio cannot be controlled via code either. [Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to be using flowplayer HTML5.  Follow their setup [documentation](http://flowplayer.org/docs/)
You can achieve this by manually installing flowplayer (I'm currently using v.5.4) to a div container via JavaScript, then accessing the fp objects "load()" method
Manual installation is explained [here](http://flowplayer.org/docs/index.html#manual-installation)
I've left the video source blank because my load method will apply an array of sources to the fp object.  I would include a valid url for your video poster, so your users aren't left with without hope ;)

HTML:

```
<div id="fp-cnt" class="container">  
   <video id="html5_video" poster="[URL]" >
      <source type="application/x-mpegurl" src="[BLANK ON PURPOSE]">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="[BLANK ON PURPOSE]"/> 
   </video>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 <script>       
        function loadFlowPlayer() {
           // install flowplayer to an element with id "fp-cnt"
           $("#fp-cnt").flowplayer({});

           var _elm = document.getElementById("fp-cnt");
           var _obj = flowplayer(_elm);

           _obj.load([
               { mpegurl: "[URL]" },
               {     mp4: "[URL]"  }
            ]);
        }

 </script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think an autoplay option is possible on ios devices.

Follow the following configuration:

1. `splash: true;`
2. use `api.toggle();` where api comprises of methods and properties of flowplayer